# How to get parent item value in child items list from xml using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've an xml which has multiple blocks in it as per below.

```
declare @Query as xml,
@poxmldoc INT

set @Query='<ProductionOrder><Header><MessageID>00000005</MessageID></Header><Body>ProductionOrderDetails>Workorder_ID>100</Workorder_ID<Item_ID>4010124</Item_ID<Publisheddata></Publisheddata><BOM><Position>1</Position><Item_ID>111</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>100</BOM_Qty><UoM>Liters</UoM>
</BOM><BOM><Position>2</Position><Item_ID>222</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>101</BOM_Qty><UoM>Kilograms</UoM></BOM><BOM><Position>3</Position><Item_ID>333</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>102</BOM_Qty><UoM>Kilograms</UoM></BOM></ProductionOrderDetails><ProductionOrderDetails><Workorder_ID>101</Workorder_ID><Item_ID>4010124</Item_ID><Publisheddata></Publisheddata><BOM><Position>1</Position><Item_ID>111</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>103</BOM_Qty><UoM>Liters</UoM></BOM><BOM><Position>2</Position><Item_ID>222</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>104</BOM_Qty><UoM>Kilograms</UoM></BOM><BOM><Position>3</Position><Item_ID>333</Item_ID><BOM_Qty>105</BOM_Qty><UoM>Kilograms</UoM></BOM></ProductionOrderDetails></Body></ProductionOrder>'
```

When I execute this query

```
EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @poxmldoc OUTPUT, @Query

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML(@poxmldoc, '/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails/BOM',2)
     WITH (Position INT 'Position',
           Item_ID NVARCHAR(40) 'Item_ID',
           BOM_Qty FLOAT 'BOM_Qty',
           UoM NVARCHAR(40) 'UoM')
```

I get this output:

```
Position    Item_ID BOM_Qty UoM
------------------------------------
1            111    100     Liters
2            222    101     Kilograms
3            333    102     Kilograms
1            111    103     Liters
2            222    104     Kilograms
3            333    105     Kilograms
```

How to get the `<Workorder_ID>` tag value along with this result.

Like this:

```
Position    Item_ID BOM_Qty UoM        Wo_Id
---------------------------------------------
1            111    100     Liters     100
2            222    101     Kilograms  100
3            333    102     Kilograms  100
1            111    103     Liters     101  
2            222    104     Kilograms  101
3            333    105     Kilograms  101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `@Query` XML variable, you could this to use this native XQuery to get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    POSITION = XC.value('(Position)[1]', 'int'),
    ItemID = XC.value('(Item_ID)[1]', 'int'),
    BomQty = XC.value('(BOM_Qty)[1]', 'int'),
    UnitOfMeasure = XC.value('(UoM)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Workorder_ID = XC.value('(../Workorder_ID)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @Query.nodes('/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails/BOM') AS XT(XC)
```

By specifying the `(../Workorder_ID)` XPath, you're basically accessing the parent element of your `<BOM>` element in question.

Comment: My xml will have namespace also. So then how can we get result.ex:

Comment: @user3237193: if you have XML namespaces, check out the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES()` construct in T-SQL - see the [official MSDN documentation for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath/XQuery. ie:

```
select  
    p.value('Position[1]','int'),
    p.value('Item_ID[1]','int'),
    p.value('BOM_Qty[1]','int'),
    p.value('UoM[1]','varchar(20)'),
    p.value('../Workorder_ID[1]','int')

from 
    @query.nodes('/ProductionOrder/Body/ProductionOrderDetails/BOM') x(p)
```